# Formal justification of Random phase approximation on lattice

Tags: condensed-matter

In case of the interacting electronic gas the justification of the random phase approximation is that ring diagrams are the most divergent terms for each order in the high-density limit. This is usually expressed via dimensionless distance parameter goes to zero
$r_s\propto 1\(a_0 k_f) \rightarrow 0$
where $a_0$ would be Bohr radius and $k_f$ is the Fermi momentum.

My question is how does this relate to the lattice problem. What is the corresponding high-density limit ?

Alternative way to derive RPA is via the Luttinger-Ward functional, where we do weak coupling expansion in the interaction and the lowest order corresponds to the RPA-like equation (well if we are more precise in the LW function we have dressed propagators, but let's leave this aside).

How can one connect these two justifications for the RPA like equations on the lattice?